# Set Based Solution to call a stored procedure for each row in a view

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, exec, set-based

I would like to call a stored procedure for each row returned in a database view and pass values from the row to the stored procedure. Note that the data within the view does NOT contain an ID column (or any unique column).

I see that using cursors and WHILE loops aren't recommended.

Does anyone have an example they can share?

Comment: Would it be possible to not pass values into a procedure, but rather have the procedure select and manipulate data within itself? This would be the optimal approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify the stored procedure as it is supplied by a commercial piece of software and I do not want to alter it in anyway.

Comment: Then your only option is a cursor.

Comment: Thank you Jaaz. I ended up using a WHILE loop to call the stored procedure for each record in the view and I used ROW_NUMBER() to provide a unique identifier for each row in the view.